# Bootstrap 3 popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a popover which displays the image:
my html:

```
 %a#btn2{"data-content" => "#{ image_tag CarConfiguration.last.image_url.to_s}".html_safe ,"data-placement" => "bottom"} Click to toggle popover
```

my js:

```
$('#btn2').popover trigger: "hover", html: true
```

I want to export this fragment to my js: 
`"data-content" => "#{ image_tag CarConfiguration.last.image_url.to_s}"`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the content in the js function that defines the popover.

It would be something like this:

```
var myPopoverContent = "#{ image_tag CarConfiguration.last.image_url.to_s}".html_safe;

$('#btn2').popover({
   trigger: 'hover',
   html: true,
   content: myPopoverContent

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afolkesson/s9L9A/

Comment: Thank's for help. But this code isn't work properly. The problem is with: var myPopoverContent = "#{ image_tag CarConfiguration.last.image_url.to_s}".html_safe;
It not load this photo. I don't know how can I evaluate ruby code in javascript.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ruby-on-rails but if you can return it as the data-content tag, then you could add a hidden input and set the value to the url. Like so:
    %a#hiddenInput{"value" => "#{ image_tag CarConfiguration.last.image_url.to_s}".html_safe}

Then you can retrieve the value in js code like so:
   var myPopoverContent = $("#hiddenInput").val()